# Why this product is not getting updated in magento through magmi?

Tags: magento, magmi

**CSV file**

```
name,store,storename,short_description,description,special_price,meta_keyword,color,
ProductId,sku,manufacturer,size,features,media_gallery,ingredients,category_ids,
meta_title,meta_description,price,datecrawled,gender,documenturl,image,ptype,age,
click,style,material,status

"Karen Millen Testing Crew neck beaded cardigan 
Black Size M",store_3619,,"Karen Millen Crew neck beaded cardigan Black Size M",
"Karen Millen Crew neck beaded cardigan Black Size M: Crew neck fine knit cardigan
 with beaded placket and invisible snap fastenings",85.00,,,505423602,
 a3-p4294967295-5054236022119z,"Karen Millen",,,http://ecx.images- amazon.com/images/I/31Pa0v6YP5L._SX300_SY300_.jpg,,64,,,80.00,,,,http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31Pa0v6YP5L._SX300_SY300_.jpg,,,http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=1WGQQZHVR3w&offerid=284485.5054236022119&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fus.karenmillen.com%2FKaren-Millen-Crew-beaded-cardigan%2Fdp%2FB00O128TH4,,,1
```

Above is my csv file.
I want to update same record in magento through magmi.
But existing product with same sku  is not getting updated.
please help

Comment: Please improve your question with some proper formatting, an error message, some code and what solutions you already tried.

Comment: I am getting no error but product is not getting updated.

Comment: To update i have used -create mode.

Comment: Do you get any errors from magmi? Are you sure the sku is correct? Try tweaking the csv file to firstly create a new product from it, check that imports correctly. Then modify, say, the price and see if that updates correctly. With magmi I find it's always best to start from a known position and change things slowly.

Comment: I am not getting any errors from magmi. SKU is correct. for the first time product is imported in database. but when i keep sku same and change price and name to update same product. It is not going to update.

Answer (score 0):

In magmi we have one options
   Cerate New
   Update Existing Items some thing like on the top of the page
select the option Update existing Items and run it

i think its help for you

thanks,
Ram Sampathi